# ClassCastException with Reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I try to analyze runtime information with reflections. The class I try to analyze has a static array of type `me.instrumentor.InstrumentStackElem` and I want to access and copy it using reflections.

The code looks like this:

```
final Field stack = this.object.getClass().getDeclaredField("ise_array");
stack.setAccessible(true);
final Object arr = stack.get(null);
final InstrumentStackElem[] tmp = new InstrumentStackElem[Array.getLength(arr)];
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    tmp[i] = (InstrumentStackElem) Array.get(arr, i);
}
```

When I try to run it, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: me.instrumentor.InstrumentStackElem cannot be cast to me.instrumentor.InstrumentStackElem` at the line in the for loop.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You declare tmp to be final, which means you can not change it. In the loop though, you're trying to change tmp. This is not possible

Comment: No. Final means I only can't change the reference, which I'm not doing here. This would lead to a compile error if it was the case.

Comment: in line 3 `final Object arr = stack.get(null);`, the null is wrong. Read the java doc.

Comment: @mike http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29 This one ?

Comment: The type check should be redundant, as I know that the type is the right one. Also the exception has the same classes. I'll try it though.
The `null` is correct, as it's a static field.

Comment: @mike If it's a static field null is fine. Anyway this exception could be throw if the two classes are loaded by two different ClassLoaders

Comment: Ah, he already wrote `static` array!

Comment: Why are you using reflection when you are inside the class where you use reflection on? However, when this is a child class of the parent, you should try casting the object to the parent first. I am just guessing here, thus this is a comment and not an answer

Comment: I'm not inside the class I use the reflection on.

The `instanceof` check returns false. I guess you are right with the classloader. Is there a nice workaround for this? Using the same ClassLoader is no option, I'd have to rewrite the whole codebase.

Comment: If you don't use the same classloader, same java code results in different class files, that are not equal. You drop the concrete type and work on objects? Maybe that's an option?

Comment: Well I need to get some data out of the objects, but they all have primitve array types. So I guess I'll extract them directly with reflections and work on them that way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've revised the solution. The copy itself is now an array of the source's component type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's sufficient for you to work on raw objects, you can try this solution. It enables you to work with arbitrary types and further you don't have to worry about different class loaders. A properly implemented `toString()` would be helpful too, I guess.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Integer[] targetArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field arrayMember = Main.class.getDeclaredField("targetArray");
        arrayMember.setAccessible(true);

        Object array = arrayMember.get(null);

        int length = Array.getLength(array);

        // get class of array element
        Class<? extends Object> elementType = array.getClass().getComponentType();
        Object copy = Array.newInstance(elementType, length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Array.set(copy, i, Array.get(array, i));
        }

        // if you know the type, you can cast
        if (Integer[].class.isInstance(copy)) {
            System.out.println("Integer[].class.isInstance(copy) == true");
            Integer[] copiedArray = Integer[].class.cast(copy);
            for (Integer i : copiedArray)
                System.out.println(i);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Array.get(copy, i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Integer[].class.isInstance(copy) == true
0
1
2
3
4
5
```